# java pattern matching on records

Tags: java

I'm using java 17.

Here my code get me a compilation error:

```java
DomainFailure.DomainError cause = new InvalidReferenceTransactionIdError(TransactionId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
String message = switch (cause) {
    case InvalidReferenceUniqueIdentifierError e -> e.referenceUniqueIdentifier().toString();
    case InvalidReferenceTransactionIdError e -> e.transactionId().toString();
};
```

Here my  `record`s:

```java
public record InvalidReferenceUniqueIdentifierError(ReferenceUniqueIdentifier referenceUniqueIdentifier)
        implements DomainFailure.DomainError {
}

public record InvalidReferenceTransactionIdError(TransactionId transactionId)
        implements DomainFailure.DomainError {
}
```

`domainFailre.domainError` is:

```java
public sealed static interface DomainError permits DomainReferenceFailure.InvalidReferenceTransactionIdError,
        DomainReferenceFailure.InvalidReferenceUniqueIdentifierError {
}
```

Currently, I'm getting this compilation message:

> Syntax error on token "e", delete this token

I don't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try deleting the token?

Comment: IIUC, pattern matching for switch in Java 17 is only a preview feature, so try running with `--enable-preview`.

Comment: It's not in JDK17, or only as a preview feature. I'd install JDK22 and try there.

Comment: Is `DomainFailure` the name of a [Java] package? In other words, is interface `DomainError` in package `DomainFailure`?

Comment: According to [JDK 17 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/17-relnote-issues.html), _pattern matching for switch_ is included as a preview feature. Also, _sealed classes_ were finalized in JDK 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, Java 17 only includes Pattern Matching for switch ([JEP 406](https://openjdk.org/jeps/406)) as a preview feature. To be able to use it under Java 17, you need to *compile* **and** *run* your application with the `--enable-preview` flag (and the `--release 17` flag when compiling).

Alternatively, switch to [Java 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_21) (or higher), as there the feature was finalized as [JEP 441](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441), and no longer needs `--enable-preview` to compile and run. Be aware there were syntax changes between Java 17 (JEP 406) and the finalized syntax of Java 21 (JEP 441).

That said, when I compile your code with Java 17 (without `--enable-preview`), I get the following error instead of the error you mention:

```
Main.java:6: error: patterns in switch statements are a preview feature and are disabled by default.
            case InvalidReferenceUniqueIdentifierError e -> e.referenceUniqueIdentifier().toString();
                 ^
  (use --enable-preview to enable patterns in switch statements)
1 error
```

So maybe you're not even using Java 17, or maybe it's an error produced by your IDE instead of Java.